# Is it possible to put JW Player alongside a video gallery?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, jwplayer

Ok, I have on my joomla site a videogallery (Name: Apptha contus hd video share). The problem of this video gallery is that is not html5. So the videos of the gallery can not be played by mobile device. So I want to add a button at the bottom (available only for mobile device ) of the player that open the JW Player that must contain the same video information (Thumb url, Video url) of the player above him.

I know how to script the button,  but my problem is how to change the JW Player code to get video and thumb information from the database. Any tips?

Comment: Does the video gallery already come with an older version of the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default mobile devices does not support flash players and supports only HTML5 player. If you have flash player in your mobile, then it is possible to play the videos. Also HTML5 players does not support except **.mp4 with H264 (HD)** format videos. We can play embed videos like YouTube, Vimeo etc., So to replace the video share player with JW player, you need to customize the code. You need to replace the  code with JW Player embed code in **default_player.php** in **components/com_contushdvideoshare/views/player/tmpl/** path. You can find **$this->htmlVideoDetails** variable in that file. this will return the current video detail from database. You can pass the required detail from this array variable to JW Player embed code. Also make sure to place the HTML5 player code. So that it will work in mobile device too.